# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ReportsController#import unknown attribute '' for Guardian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to import excel of Guardian Details.But when i choose excel to   import it gives me error
**unknown attribute '' for Guardian**

This is my code:

guardian.rb

```
class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  COLUMNS_TO_STRING = ["student_id"] # and so on
  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      row = clean_for row, COLUMNS_TO_STRING
      record = Guardian.find_by(:student_id => row["student_id"]) || new
      record.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
      record.create!
    end
  end

  def self.clean_for row_as_hash, string_columns_array
    row_as_hash.each do |key, value|
      if string_columns_array.include?key
        row_as_hash[key] = value.to_i.to_s
      end
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
end
```

report_controller.rb

```
def import
 Guardian.import(params[:file])
 redirect_to import_reports_path, notice: "Students imported."
end
```

import.html.erb

```
<h1>IMPORT</h1>
<div class = "well">
<p>
<%= form_tag import_reports_path,url:{action:   'import_excel',controller: 'reports'}, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file%>
    <br>
  <%= submit_tag "Import",class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post whole message of the error? Would be easier to see where exactly the error comes from.

One more thing: I guess url hash in form_tag is not necessary.

Comment: I am getting error on this line `record.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)`

Comment: Could you check what `row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)` returns? The problem is probably located in the ::clean_for, so you could try to debug it.

Comment: `["first_name",
 "last_name",
 "relation",
 "student_id",
 "email",
 "office_phone1",
 "office_phone2",
 "mobile_phone",
 "office_address_line1",
 nil,
 "office_address_line2",
 "city",
 "state",
 "country_id",
 "dob",
 "occupation",
 "income",
 "education"]` thanks for the answer there was nil value in excel I debugged it and its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in excel was nil so i got an error as   **ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ReportsController#import   unknown attribute '' for Guardian**

```
Debugging solved my problem:
`pry(Guardian)> header = spreadsheet.row(1)
 => ["first_name",
 "last_name",
 "relation",
 "student_id",
 "email",
 "office_phone1",
 "office_phone2",
 "mobile_phone",
 "office_address_line1",
 nil,
 "office_address_line2",
 "city",
 "state",
 "country_id",
 "dob",
 "occupation",
 "income",
 "education"]`
```